# Javascript SetTimeOut function Does Not Work Somehow

Tags: javascript, settimeout

My system fatches data every 500 ms and my screen is full of html tables apart from each other . And every cell has unique key attribute. I am caching all of them anyway.

I have a global JavaScript object(_cellColorTimeouts) which contains settimeout functions for cellElements of tableRows that I mentioned above. After caching of cells, system creates timeout functions which is to wipe css out for spesific cell (in 3000ms).

In code block below uiElementKey_X and uiElementKey_Y are exact same but cached like are different. Adding unique suffix into table id makes them different. This proccess is done for row and cell items aswell.

example of _cellColorTimeouts data is

```
//array object keys are names of unique cell items.
_cellColorTimeouts = [uiElementKey_X_1, uiElementKey_X_2, uiElementKey_X_3,
                      uiElementKey_Y_1, uiElementKey_X_2, uiElementKey_Y_3];

. 
. //does somethings to change cell colour
.

    //after 3 seconds i need to clear css of this cell without looping the dom so i do it via cached dom.
    if (_cellColorTimeouts.hasOwnProperty(uiElementKey) && _cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey] != null) {
         clearTimeout(_cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey]);
         _cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey] = null;
       }
       _cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey] = setTimeout(function () {
               clearColourOfCell(cell);
       }, 3000);
}

function clearColourOfCell(cell) {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = cell.rowBGColour;
    cell.style.color = "black";
    _cellColorTimeouts[cell.uiElementKey] == null;
    clearTimeout(_cellColorTimeouts[cell.uiElementKey]);
}
```

So the problem is settimeout function is not working for the first table but second is totally fine. I have checked is there any settimeout function return id from global, yes it has. For the first table somehow it does not work. I know this question is too unique for my case but any idea will be preciated?

---- EDIT  ---- FULL FUNCTION UNCUT VERSION -----

```
function setWidgetData(widgetId, rowId, colId, value, colIndex) {
"use strict";

// check colIndex
if (colIndex === undefined || colIndex === null) {
    colIndex = 0;
}

// loop on ui tables
var uiTables = _widgetUIElements[widgetId];
//var timeout;
for (var tableId in uiTables) {
    var uiTable = uiTables[tableId];
    var uiElementKey = tableId + "#" + rowId + "#" + colId + "#" + colIndex;
    var cellCachedObject = uiTable[uiElementKey];

    // check cell
    if (cellCachedObject == undefined) {
        //console.log("cell is undefined : " + "widgetId : " + widgetId + " - " + "rowId : " + rowId + " - " + "colId : " + colId + " - " + "colIndex : " + colIndex);
    }
    else {
        // get cell
        var cell = cellCachedObject["domElement"];
        // set sell value
        var cellValue = value;

        // is value numeric? it means we will make some conversions on value
        if (isNumeric(cellValue)) {
            var canPaint = false;
            // check cell entity
            switch (cellCachedObject["entity"]) {
                // date-time?           
                case "DATETIME":
                    // convert unix date time to readable date time
                    cellValue = new Date(fixDecimalSeparator(cellValue) * 1000);
                    cellValue = fixDateTimeDigits((cellValue.getDate())) + "/" + fixDateTimeDigits((cellValue.getMonth() + 1)) + " " + fixDateTimeDigits(cellValue.getHours()) + ":" + fixDateTimeDigits(cellValue.getMinutes());
                    break;
                // date?           
                case "DATE":
                    // convert unix date time to readable date time
                    cellValue = new Date(fixDecimalSeparator(cellValue) * 1000);
                    cellValue = fixDateTimeDigits((cellValue.getDate())) + "/" + fixDateTimeDigits((cellValue.getMonth() + 1));
                    break;
                // numeric?          
                case "NR":
                    // fix "," character in value
                    cellValue = fixDecimalSeparator(cellValue);
                    //just format the presicion
                    cellValue = number_format(cellValue, cellCachedObject["precision"], '.', ',');
                    canPaint = true;
                    break;
                // other?           
                default:
                    // fix "," character in value
                    cellValue = fixDecimalSeparator(cellValue);
                    // if cell is number, no entity conversion
                    // entity convertion
                    cellValue = entityConverter(cellCachedObject["entity"], cellCachedObject["entityTo"], cellValue);
                    cellValue = new Number(cellValue).toFixed(cellCachedObject["precision"]);

                    // if widget currency is not USD. it means user selected currency from currency list or default user currency
                    if (cellCachedObject["isConvertable"]) {
                        // this scoop is not active with the new xml. if FOREX1 widget entity is RECIPCUR but never should not be
                        if (cellCachedObject["widgetIsFOREX1"]) {
                            cellValue = _currencyConverter.convertTrend(cellValue, cellCachedObject.currencyValueType, cellCachedObject["currencyTo"], cellCachedObject["rowId"], cellValue);
                        }
                        else {
                            cellValue = _currencyConverter.convert(cellValue, cellCachedObject["currency"], null, cellCachedObject["precision"]);
                        }
                    }
                    canPaint = true;
            }

            // if it is not date time
            if (canPaint) {
                // get current value of cell
                var currentValue = cell.getAttribute("currentValue");
                // check current value of cell make them coloured.
                if (currentValue !== undefined) {
                    // new value is bigger than old value
                    var newVal = parseFloat(value);
                    var oldVal = parseFloat(currentValue);
                    var rowBGColour = cellCachedObject["rowBGColor"];
                    cell.rowBGColour = rowBGColour;
                    cell.uiElementKey = uiElementKey;
                    if (newVal > oldVal) {
                        //cell.css({ "background-color": "Green", "color": "White" });
                        cell.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                        cell.style.color = "white";
                    }
                    // new value is smaller than old value
                    if (newVal < oldVal) {
                        //cell.css({ "background-color": "Red", "color": "White" });
                        cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                        cell.style.color = "white";
                    }
                    if (_cellColorTimeouts.hasOwnProperty(uiElementKey) && _cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey] != null) {
                        clearTimeout(_cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey]);
                        _cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey] = null;
                    }
                    _cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey] = setTimeout(function () {
                        return function () {
                            clearColourOfCell(cell);
                        };
                    } (cell), 3000);
                    newVal = oldVal = rowBGColour = null;
                }
                currentValue = null;
            }
            canPaint = null;

            // set new value as a current value
            cell.setAttribute("currentValue", value);
        }

        cell.innerHTML = '';
        cell.innerHTML = cellValue;

        cellValue = null;
    }

    uiTable = uiElementKey = cellCachedObject = null;
}

uiTables = null;
}
```

Comment: You might want to change the comparison (`==`) to an assignment (`=`) in the third from last row of the code sample. And call `clearTimeout` before setting the array element to `null`.

Comment: my case does not go through clearColourOfCell.

Comment: Let me guess: that call to `setTimeout()` is in a loop, and the variable `cell` changes on each iteration of the loop, right?

Comment: cell does not have to be changed i mean if the value changed in cycle of 500 ms i need to show the changement on cell and after 3 secs i have to clear css of changed cell to default.

Comment: The point is that you're setting up the timeout handler such that the handler has code that references a variable in the closure, and multiple such handlers will all reference the same variable.

Comment: OK well based on your update, you definitely need to set the timeout handler as I described in my answer. As to why it doesn't work, well, I'm not sure. It could be something about the way you're creating that "cache".

Comment: i suspect about caching they seem like different object but probably the last table only being cached. I am going go though that part of code and update here thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post enough code for me to know for sure that this is the problem, but it's a good bet:

```
   _cellColorTimeouts[uiElementKey] = setTimeout(function () {
      return function() {
           clearColourOfCell(cell);
      };
   }(cell), 3000);
```

By setting up the timeout handler like that, you ensure that the handler has its own private **copy** of that "cell" variable, so that no matter how "cell" is changed before the handler is finally invoked, that copy will retain the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i have wrote console.log() to print uiElemntKey  out into clearColourOfCell so it prints only table Y keys i mean if the cell would be empty that'd give an error i suppose anyway i will change the code as you posted and will give info after

Comment: @afacanerman well the main problem is that you haven't posted enough of your code, I don't think. Exactly how does the variable "cell" get its value(s)?

Comment: this is only small part of the function. Believe me it is huge and i can't post all code here. i will update my question with full function  now i hope it works.